# if statement from result EditText

Tags: android, if-statement

I want to change image from result class using if, but i don't know how to show image from result.getText. the result from 1 to 100.

SOLVED

```
CalculatorValue cv = new CalculatorValue ();
                    String calculationVal= cv.calculationVal(num1+ "compare" + num2);

                Result.setText(calculationVal+ " %");
if (result < 10){
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_110);
    }
```

can you kindly help me to give me example in this case

thank you

the code is not working

```
if (result < 10){
     // your code
} 
if (result >10 && result <15){
     // your code
}
else
```

I create Calculation.class and I put statement If in MainActivity.class

this code :

```
 CalculatorValue cv = new CalculatorValue ();
                    String calculationVal= cv.calculationVal(num1+ "compare" + num2);

                Result.setText(calculationVal+ " %");
if (result < 10){
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_110);
    }
```

The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Comment: You should read the basic...

Answer (score 3):

There is a big syntax error in your case . This is an orphaned expression which can bring the compiler on its knees trying to figure out :

```
if (result >10 <15) // This is incomprehensible , doesn't work.
```

Try this :

```
if (result < 10){
     // your code
} 
if (result >10 && result <15){
     // your code
}
else
  ....
```

**After the question was edited:**

> The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Clearly suggests that `result` is a `String` , hence it is unable to use the `<` to compare . One way is to convert `result` to an `int` , `Integer.parseInt(result)` , saying that please take care that `result` is a numeric `String` which can be converted to a valid `int` like `12`,`143`,`0`. This won't work `12_3` ...

Comment: your code is not working 

    if (result < 10){
         // your code
    } 
    if (result >10 && result <15){
         // your code
    }
    else

I create Calculation.class and I put statement If in MainActivit.class

this code :

   

     CalculatorValue cv = new CalculatorValue ();
            String calculationVal= cv.calculationVal(num1+ "compare" + num2);
    
        Result.setText(calculationVal+ " %");
    if (result < 10){
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_110);
        } 

The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int